# MVC, Nhibernate, castle, windsor Integrated testing not writing to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, castle-windsor, integration-testing

We are attempting to write some integrated tests to a web app which uses MVC, Nhibernate, castle, windsor and sharpArch.  When we step thru the tests, they hit all the methods correctly, but do not write any data to the database.  We are using a repository model, and Nhibernate save.  The code is working when run from the website.  We are not using DI in the Integrated tests, which is a project in the web app solution.  There are no errors thrown.
Nhibernate  is initialized in the integration tests in the global as

```
NHibernateSession.Init(WebSessionStorage,
                               new string[] { binPath },
                               null,
                               appconfigPath,
                               configuration, null, null);
```

Where binPath is the path to dll containing the Nhibernate maps and classes and appconfigPath is the path to the bin of the website. The NHibernateSession appears to be populated.

ANY ideas, suggestions welcomed.

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that you haven't forgotten about transaction handling (and committing them (thus triggering flush)) in you tests.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Since the statement I am working with uses the Nhiberante SEssion save, and the function itself works, I am assuming that the save is automatically flushed.  I should have mentioned and have edited the question to include that this is a MVC Project.

Comment: ISession.Save() does NOT mean "run an SQL INSERT right now". It means "mark this object as persistent". If the database is responsible for generating the identifier, then an INSERT statement will be run as a side effect. If NHibernate or the application is in charge of identifiers, the INSERT won't run until a flush is performed. Since this usually happens on transaction commit, any difference in transaction handling between production and tests might be interesting to the problem.

Comment: I was wrong.  I had to get the Nhibernate Session in the test, then do a begin transaction before calling the function and a commit after.  Thanks!